# What is the difference between using true or false inside update_user_meta()

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to update a meta value inside my database using update_user_meta. If I pass true into the function it doesn't update the meta value, but if I use false it does update. So whats the difference between the two?

```
update_user_meta(1, 'event_year', '8', true);
update_user_meta(1, 'event_year', '8', false);
```

Comment: Take a look at [update_user_meta reference](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/update_user_meta)

Answer (score 0):

The description for last parameter is not the right method you are following.

it will be like,

```
//changes 'true' to '8'
update_user_meta(1, 'event_year', '8', true);
```

the 3rd parameter will replace with 4th parameter, so in your case it will replace true with 8

This function has 4 parameters:

```
$user_id : The user id.
$meta_key : Metadata name to be updated.
$meta_value : Metadata new value.
$prev_value :previous value of metadata. It is optional so if supplied, only metadata with that value will be updated otherwise all metadata with supplied $meta_key will be updated.
```

Comment: So why would it not update when using true? Is it because it already has a value?

Comment: Reread the link you provided. The description for parameter is "Previous value to check before removing." So it is NOT check/not check, it is a VALUE.

Comment: @Reece were you stuck,? why you add true or false after the update_meta ?

Answer (score 0):

Okay, referring to https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/update_user_meta we can say that **fourth** parameter defines

```
> Previous __value__ to check before removing.
```

See, it is **THE VALUE** that is checked. So, before updating your `event_year` field `wp` checks if this field stores this defined value. And you say - the stored value is `true`. I'm not really sure how **true** is converted in query text, but probably after passing it to query text `wp` cannot confirm that removed value is same as **true**. That's why update does not happen.

In case of `false` (and `false` can be considered same as default value for fourth parameter - `''` (empty string)) you tell `wp` - nothing to check here, just update if value has changed.

Answer (score 0):

$prev_value => Optional. If specified, only update existing metadata entries with the specified value. Otherwise, update all entries.

`update_user_meta()` relays to `update_metadata()` and this explanation is there https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/5.2.1/src/wp-includes/meta.php LINE 151